# How to connect Android and IOS to SQL Server

Tags: android, ios, sql-server, database-connection

can someone please help, I need to develop a android app that will then be converted to IOS using Xamarin however how or what it the best way to connect to a SQL sever database that is hosted? I will have a connection string

Comment: Generally you don't.  Unless you're trying to write database management tools, you probably want a webservice inbetween for security and performance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether direct connection from android to SQL server is possible but I used to connect via a WebServer Eg. Apache Tomcat by deploying any WebApplication that have access to database server.

The thing how it works is, we will pass parameters from android through NameValuePairs/Json types and these parameters are parsed by server application (Processing business logic) and gives back the response in String/Json format.

Comment: So will I be able to have a webservice that connects to the SQL database and then just sends XML to the android app?